# psql how to copy output of query with single whitespace between columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, dump

I want to create update commands from a table (using `select` queries) like so:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET col=', col, 'WHERE id=', id, ';' FROM table1;
```

I want to output this query to stdout with `COPY`. I am doing this:

```
COPY (SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET col=', col, 'WHERE id=', id FROM table1) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ' ';
```

The problem is that this is outputing the columns separated by `\`  not just whitespace:

```
UPDATE\ table1\ SET\ col=23 WHERE\ id= 345;
```

How can I just output columns with single whitespaces in between.

Comment: `SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET col=' || col || 'WHERE id='||` maybe?? Or `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'UPDATE table1.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to produce SQL with SQL queries is through the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function, producing the query in a single column, like this:

```
SELECT format('UPDATE table1 SET col=%s WHERE id=%s;'
              ,col, id) FROM table1;
```

The format specifier `%L` can be used instead of `%s` to have properly quoted literals, in order to avoid SQL injection (or `%I` for identifiers like table names or column names).

The query being in a single column, you won't have the problem of the separator between columns.

That being said, it's not clear why you see backslashes before spaces when using `DELIMITER ' '` with COPY, because COPY itself doesn't do that. Example:

```
COPY (select 'ab', 'cd') TO STDOUT delimiter ' ';
```

results in:

```
ab cd
```